# How to add newline when I return array in React?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, create-react-app

I needed to print a string, "dummy data".

So I made a function that returns array which has string "dummy data" in it.
I was able to print "dummy data dummy data dummy data ...". However, I want to put newline each string. Then it will looks like,

...
dummy data
dummy data
dummy data
...

How can I do it?

[Sample image of code and result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71fOp.png)

```
class Content extends Component {
  dummyDataLoop = () => {
    var rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      rows.push("dummy data");
    }
    return rows;
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        <div>[CONTENT AREA START]</div>
        {this.dummyDataLoop()}
        <div>[CONTENT AREA END]</div>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to wrap each line to a block level element or you can use line break

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the string in a `<div>` and then push it into array.

```
dummyDataLoop = () => {
  var rows = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    rows.push(<div>dummy data</div>);
  }
  return rows;
};
```

Another way is to use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and spread operator to shorten the code.

```
dummyDataLoop = () => [...Array(10)].map(x => <div>dummy data</div>)
```

Comment: @MasonYMKoh Glad to help you. Also see the second of doing the same thing. Actually creating an empty array and pushing elements to it is not considered a clean code.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap `dummy data` with `div` tag before pushing it to array like this

```
<div>dummy data</div>
```

---

You can change your code to,

```
dummyDataLoop = () => {
    var rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      rows.push(<div>dummy data</div>);   // notice change in this line
    }
    return rows;
};

  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        <div>[CONTENT AREA START]</div>
        {this.dummyDataLoop()}
        <div>[CONTENT AREA END]</div>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is much simple. Use `map` to iterate the array then return it wrapped in a

tag.

```
class Content extends Component {
  dummyDataLoop = () => {
    var rows = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      rows.push("dummy data");
    }
    return rows;
  };
  render() {
    return (
      <article>
        <div>[CONTENT AREA START]</div>
        {this.dummyDataLoop().map((item, index) => <p key={index}>{item}</p>)}
        <div>[CONTENT AREA END]</div>
      </article>
    );
  }
}
```